# Wordpress: how to make post (not page) on separate subdomain?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible make wordpress post on separate subdomain?

e.g.

domain.com/articles/myarticle3.html

myarticle3.domain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hosting provider should support wildcard subdomains.
This plugin will help
https://webostock.com/market-item/wordpress-post-subdomain-pro-2/31781/